# Is there a possibility to add nth-child for a javascript variable? I need to add it to typescript code

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, css-selectors, react-typescript

[image]

This is inside a .tsx file. The styles variable is applied as `styles={styles}`

```
var styles = {
  bmBurgerBars: {
    height: '10px',
    right: '20px'
  }
  //nth child for bmBars
}
```

I have tried the below code but it is not implementing on the UI

```
var styles = {
  bmBurgerBars: {
    height: '10px',
    right: '20px',
    '&:nth-child(2)': {
      width: '80%',
      left: '7px',
      background: '#111'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That probably depends on the library you are using for CSS in JavaScript. Which library are you using?

Comment: I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-burger-menu wherein I need to add nth-child for bmBurgerBars.

Comment: So you are not using a CSS-in-JS library. It looks like  react-burger-menu simply applies the style provided by JS as inline styles, so you can't use the `:nth-child` selector. You can always add such rules in a normal CSS file though, as explained in https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-burger-menu#styling

Comment: I am following `var styles = { // css here }` then `<Menu styles={ styles } />` as mentioned but it is not implementing on the UI.

Comment: Yes, it can't work because it's using inline styles. You have to specify that rule in a proper CSS file for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a library such as Material UI (or similar/forked), you can use the following spec:

```js
var styles = {
  bmBars: {
    height: '10px',
    right: '20px',
    '&:nth-child(n)': {
      color: 'red'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response. This syntax works but it is not implementing on UI. I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-burger-menu wherein I am adding nth-child to bmBurgerBars.

Comment: Could you expand your question with an edit to include some more details?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question along with screenshort.